# VB.NET: DataGridView колонка с чекбоксами: добавление/удаление индексов строки в список/массив

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Работаю с формами в VB.NET

Имеется DatagridView таблица с колонкой чекбоксов.

Смотрите картинку ниже:

[image: datagridview column with chk_boxes]

Интересует вопрос: как в list добавлять индекс строки при клике в чекбокс(когда активируем статус ckecked), и удалять из list, когда убираем галочку?

Пробовал следующее, но это не верное решение:

```
 If e.ColumnIndex = chk_column.Index Then 
            If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                try                 
                   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridNames.Rows
                        Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells(5), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
                        If cell.Value Is cell.FalseValue Then
                            bList_indexes.Add( DataGridnames.CurrentCell.RowIndex)  
                            Exit For

                            Else 'If  cell.Value Is cell.TrueValue   Then
                                bList_indexes.RemoveAt(DataGridnames.CurrentCell.RowIndex) 
                        End If
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'Show the exception's message.
                    'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

                    'Throw New Exception("Something happened.")
                end try
            End If
end If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышло реализовать данным способом:

```
 Private Sub DataGridnames_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridnames.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex =  chk_column.Index Then
 
            'Reference the GridView Row.
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dataGridNames.Rows(e.RowIndex)
 
            'Set the CheckBox selection.
            row.Cells("chk_column").Value = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("chk_column").EditedFormattedValue)
 
            'If CheckBox is checked, display Message Box.
            If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("chk_column").Value) Then
                MessageBox.Show(("Selected ID: " & row.Cells(1).RowIndex))
                bList_indexes.Add(row.Cells(1).RowIndex)
            Else If Not Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("chk_column").Value) Then
                MessageBox.Show(("Deleted ID: " & row.Cells(1).RowIndex))
                bList_indexes.Remove(row.Cells(1).RowIndex)

                End If
        End If
    End Sub
```